# Selenium on raspberry pi zero 2w

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium, webdriver, alpine

I've been trying to run selenium webdriver on raspberry OS.

Basically what I did:

```
pip3 install selenium
sudo apk-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

And run this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

With these variations:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver'))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'))
```

Also tried setting binary location:

```
options.BinaryLocation = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"
```

All of it boils down to an error which is:

```
Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

I've tried reinstalling selenium, reinstalling chromium, updating everything. It always fails with status code -4 which is not very informative and hard to debug.

It seems like I'm getting `illegal operation` message whenever I try to get `chromedriver/chromium --version` which might be the clue why something is off.

Comment: "Ilegal opertation" implies the executable was compiled for the wrong [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and tried most of the stuff that people write on the internet regarding selenium and ARMv6Z.

What finally worked for the website I tried to scrape was:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659532/scrapy-and-javascript-sites-on-rasbperry-pi

So basically set `url=XHR` requests and then use:

```
import urllib.request, json 

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:

data = json.load(url)
```